# 4052 interfacaing with arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to interface 4052 demux with arduino, but my program is not working as high is not displayed on serial monitor corresponding to select lines.

```
//output coming from demux pins
int sensorValue0=A0;  
int sensorValue1=A1;
int sensorValue2=A2;
int sensorValue3=A3;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("start");
  //select pins connected A,B connected to 2 and 3
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(3,LOW);
  analogRead(sensorValue0);
  //Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) to a voltage (0 - 5V):
  int voltage0= sensorValue0 * (5.0 / 1023.0); 
  Serial.println("volatge0");
  Serial.println(voltage0); 
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at any tutorials of references on how to use `analogRead()`?

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring the value read by `analogRead()`.  You are then using the value `A0` (14) in your sum to calculate the voltage.

Instead:

```
int adcReading = analogRead(sensorValue0);
int voltage0 = adcReading * (5.0 / 1023.0);
```

Although I *think* what you really meant to write was, in total:

```
int sensorPin = A0;
int sensorValue0;//output coming from demux pins
int sensorValue1;
int sensorValue2;
int sensorValue3;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("start");
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);//selecr pins connected A,B connected to 2 and 3
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(3,LOW);
  sensorValue0 = analogRead(sensorPin);
  float voltage0 = sensorValue0 * (5.0 / 1023.0);//Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) to a voltage (0 - 5V):
  Serial.print("voltage0 = ");
  Serial.println(voltage0); 
}
```

Note that the value `sensorPin` is where you read the voltage from, and `sensorValue0` is where you store that reading. Also note the use of a `float` type to store the calculated voltage, since an `int` will give you only values of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 in this situation (so, pretty meaningless really).

Comment: actually select pins of demux are not selected according to program written.

Comment: I am assuming it's a partially written program at the moment.

Comment: sir,one more thing what should i write to control two demux in a program using inhibit pin and activate only one demux at a time..

Comment: Just use digitalWrite to activate the mux you want.

Comment: I have used digitalwrite(4,LOW); as 4 pin of arduino is connected with demux inhibit pin and demux is fuctioning but when m not using inhibit pin of demux den still demux working,not understanding whats happening.why inhibit pin not working as it should

Comment: i have used CD4052BE DEMUX